# Promethus query in grafana using $__interval

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In Prometheus querying in grafana, are these queries same resultwise:

```
sum(increase(mymetrics[$__interval]))
increase(sum(mymetrics)[$__interval])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, they are not the same. The result will not always be the same and the second query will return wrong results if your data contains resets.** This is due to the fact that your distinct counter time series may contain resets. If you sum it all up these resets to zero disappear.

The following blog-post explains this well. `increase` is really just syntactic sugar around `rate`. So the article can be also applied to `increase`.

https://www.robustperception.io/rate-then-sum-never-sum-then-rate

> Rate then sum, never sum then rate